# Any admissible classifier is a Bayes rule

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, classification

> Suppose we are trying to classify $X$ into a distribution given
> either by the density $f_1$ or $f_2$.
>
> Assume $\mathbb P_i(f_1(X)/f_2(X)=t)=0$ for $i=1$ or $2$ and for any
> $0\leq t\leq\infty$. Show that any admissible classifier is in fact a
> Bayes classification rule for some suitable choice of prior.

I am aware that a Bayes classifier for the prior $\pi=(\pi_1,\pi_2)$ is unique (hence admissible) if $$\mathbb P_i\left(\frac{\pi_1f_1(X)}{(1-\pi_1)f_2(X)}\right)=0.$$
But I am unsure how to prove this (partial) converse.

Comment: I believe you can plot all classifiers in the $(f_1,f_2)$ plane.  That should lead to an effective proof strategy.

Comment: Hi @whuber I'm not quite sure what you mean? Would you mind elaborating please? Thanks.

Comment: An early chapter of Jack Kiefer's book, *Introduction to Statistical Inference,* contains a nice (illustrated) account of this along with many mathematically tractable examples and exercises.

Comment: Thanks @whuber for the reference! So I think something along the following lines works. The set $\mathcal R$ of classifiers $\delta$ forms a closed convex set when we plot them as points, where the axes are the risks $R(\delta,f_1)$ and $R(\delta,f_2)$. Then the "bottom left boundary" of $\mathcal R$ is the set of Bayes classifiers, and it also contains all the admissible classifiers. I think this works, but I don't seem to be using the condition on $f_1(X)/f_2(X)$?